# How to keep the navigation active when accessing nesting navigation with React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Is there a way which I can navigate to a nested route and keep the main navigation active?

For example this is the main navigation `http://localhost:3000/#/tractian/assets-list` and I get an `active class` from `React Router`:

[image]

But If I navigate to a nested route the class is removed:
`http://localhost:3000/#/tractian/assets-list/asset/1`

[image]

How can I keep the class, shouldn't `react-router` understand that this is a nested route?

This is a sample of my code:

```
<HashRouter>
  <Layout>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets-list`}
        exact
        component={AssetsList}
      />
      <Route
        path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets-list/asset/:id`}
        component={AssetComponent}
     />
    </Switch>
  </Layout>
</HashRouter>
```

NAVIGATION:

````
<ul className={classes["SideNavigation--navigation-items"]}>
  <h1>LOGO</h1>
  <li>
    <NavLink to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} exact>Overview</NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <NavLink to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets-list` } exact>Ativos</NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <NavLink to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/users-list`} exact>Usuários</NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <NavLink to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/units-list`} exact>Unidades</NavLink>
  </li>
</ul>

NESTED NAVIGATION:
```jsx
<NavLink to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets-list/asset/${item.id}`}>
  TESTE
</NavLink>
````

I've tried to nest the route within the main one, but without success:

```
<Route
  path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets-list`}
  exact
  component={AssetsList}
>
  <Route
    path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets-list/asset/:id`}
    component={AssetComponent}
  />
</Route>
```

Comment: How is the active set currently ?

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to share a more complete [mcve] that includes the links that are "active" or not?

Comment: @Marko Taht what do you mean? React Router set the active class itself, what I do is just style it with css.

Comment: React router does not automatically set the active class on the navigation. You are doing something to determin if active should be put there or not.

Comment: @Marko Taht I am not, I'm just using `Navlink` and it sets the class.

Comment: @Drew Reese I just edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the `NavLink` components are ***exactly*** matching the URL path, so if you are on a nested route the parent path no longer exactly matches.

See [v5 NavLink exact prop](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/exact-bool)

Remove the `exact` prop from the links that you want to also be matched as active when a sub-route is matched and rendered.

Example:

```
<ul className={classes["SideNavigation--navigation-items"]}>
  <h1>LOGO</h1>
  <li>
    <NavLink to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} exact>
      Overview
    </NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    {/* Not exact path matching, allow sub-route active matching */}
    <NavLink to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets-list`}>
      Ativos
    </NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <NavLink to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/users-list`} exact>
      Usuários
    </NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <NavLink to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/units-list`} exact>
      Unidades
    </NavLink>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

```
<NavLink to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets-list/asset/${item.id}`}>
  TESTE
</NavLink>
```

[image: navlink sub-route matching]

[image: Edit how-to-keep-the-navigation-active-when-accessing-nesting-navigation-with-react-r]

Answer (score -1):

One way is to use the "useLocation" hook to get the current URL. You can then compare the current URL with the URL of the navigation link and base it on the difference.